# Using java, what is the most resource efficient way to pull a list files names from a folder location

Tags: java, file, memory, io

Using Java, what is the most resource efficient way to pull a 'list' of files names from a folder location. At the moment I am using the code below:-

```
           File[] files = new File(folderLocation).listFiles();
```

Before iterating through the file array and dumping the filenames only, into a Hash to be used by my application. So, bearing in mind that I only need the file name's is there a more memory efficient way to do this.

Edit:

- I am not using Java 7
- I was not actually getting a memory error but the method I'd developed was taking such a long time to run (20mins) that it is not a realistic option for the application that I am developing.

Comment: I think this is the only way to do it.

Comment: you can have look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html

Comment: Are you actually running out of memory while listing files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to differentiate between files and directories.  If not, you can use the list() function in File to return an array of strings naming the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname.  Then, you can easily construct a HashSet with that list.  For example,

```
String[] files = new File(folderLocation).list();
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(files));
```

There is also a list(FilenameFilter filter) function which accepts a file name filter and returns a list of String names.  However, it doesn't allow you to filter based on file/directory.

Comment: This appears to be alot faster Thanks, if I get a change to make a wee test I'll add the results here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(new File(folderLocation)).list()` which returned String[]. Each String is path+separator+filename. You can extract filename from this Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 7+ there is:

```
final Path dir = Paths.get(folderLocation);

final List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

try (
    final DirectoryStream<Path> dirstream
        = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir);
) {
    for (final Path entry: dirstream)
        list.add(entry.getFileName());
}
```

Also, well, [`File.listFiles()` just doesn't work](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks#Listing_files_in_a_directory.2C_oh_my).

Comment: We don't use Java 7 at the moment but I shall bear this in mind thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can check [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--)

it is mentioned in javadoc

> Path getFileName()
>   Returns the name of the file or directory denoted by this path as a Path object